# Finding the direction of rectangle from the the centre of bounding box of adjacent rectangles C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Given multiple adjacent 2D rectangles defined by the X and Y coordinates of the centre and their length and width, I would like to create the system capable to find the rectangle position relatively to world sides (4 cardinal directions + 4 inter cardinals NE, SE, SW, NW). The "world centre" is the rectangles bounding rectangle. I work with Unity and try to find any useful algorithm or C# piece of code. I would be grateful for any advice or indication of the right direction.

Comment: A list of things you want is not a *question*. Is there a *specific* question about code that you have?  Can you show us what work you've done so far?

Comment: position of the center, width and length can define a lot of different rectangles depending on orientation unless it is already "axis aligned"

Comment: @EricLippert The specific question was "how can I find the position of the rectangle (expressed in the directions of the world) in the group of adjacent rectangles relatively to their bounding box centre?". Zambari's answer gave me the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is borrowing the functionality from EventSystem - if you add any Selectable component to your RectTransforms (see how it works using a default UI Button), you can then use Selectable.FindSelectable(Vector3 direction), which works quite well

Comment: your answer gave me the idea how can I do what I wanted. I created the vector between the centre of the bounding box and the centre of rectangle and measured the angle between the assumed North vector (Y axis in my case). Thanks!